# How should I handle schema.org markup for a product with multiple sizes/prices

Tags: schema.org

While implementing schema.org markup for one of my cusomters online-shops I noticed a little difficulty. I think it's a missing option in the markup. Neighter offer nor aggregateOffer can handle this case correctly - although I think it is quite common.

- One page for one product (let's say it's a body-lotion)
- The body-lotion comes in 3 sizes, 100, 200 and 250ml
- It basically has an internal productId (BL100, BL200 and BL250) for each size as well as a EAN ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number_(EAN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number_%28EAN%29)) for each size.
- How to buy: Go on the product page, chose your size, the price changes via javascript, click add to chart

**Q**: How can I markup ONE product with MULTIPLE sizes and MULTIPLE prices correctly?

Problems:
http://schema.org/Product suggests only ONE productID which is wrong for me. If I add three offers (http://schema.org/Offer), search engines might think, the pricing is totally weird because the same product has three different offers.

http://schema.org/AggregateOffer doesn't seem right to me eighter.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Another example is material or finish. For example the same faucet comes in, chrome, nickel, bronze, and gold plate, each with their own price.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the correct way to mark up this particular scenario is by nesting several [Offers](http://schema.org/Offer) inside of a single [Product](http://schema.org/Product). To add additional information to each Offer, use an [IndividualProduct](http://schema.org/IndividualProduct). I'm not 100% sure, but this seems to work well in the Google Structured Data Testing Tool.

It looks like schema.org is still being updated with new ways to markup your products. The schema.org project pulled in a lot of structure from the [Good Relations](http://www.heppnetz.de/projects/goodrelations/) e-commerce product vocabulary. See [E-commerce SEO Using Schema.org Just Got A Lot More Granular](http://searchengineland.com/e-commerce-seo-using-schema-org-just-got-a-lot-more-granular-139236) for more information about the new vocabulary items.

Say we want to list information about Sumatra coffee beans for sale on a website. We want to sell two different sizes (12 oz. and 16 oz.) with different prices for each. However, both product sizes should have the same images ('tis just a coffee bean) and name. The structure will look something like:

```
Product (name, description, and image)
  aggregateRating
  Offer (price and priceCurrency)
    IndividualProduct (sku and weight)
  Offer (price and priceCurrency)
    IndividualProduct (sku and weight)
```

Copy and paste the following into Google's [Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=uploaded:80050114d74fabbb5988bd67f4684858) to see how Google will interpret the HTML.

<kbd>[jsFiddle display](http://jsfiddle.net/px1Ld9z8/)</kbd>

```
<article class="product" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <div class="images">
    <a href="images/product.jpg">
      <img alt="Sumatra Coffee Beans" itemprop="image" src="images/product.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <header>
      <h1 itemprop="name">Sumatra Coffee Beans</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="code">
      <span class="label">Item Number:</span>
      <span itemprop="productID">sumatra-coffee</span>
    </div>
    <div itemprop="description">
      <p>Error 418</p>
    </div>
    <div class="reviews" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
      <div class="details">
        Rated <span itemprop="ratingValue">4.5</span>/5
      </div>
      <div class="count">
        (<span itemprop="reviewCount">9</span> reviews)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="offer" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
      <div itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/IndividualProduct">
        <span class="sku" itemprop="sku">scb-ov1</span>
        – (<span itemprop="weight">12 oz.</span>)
      </div>
      <div class="price">$<span itemprop="price">14.99<span></div>
      <meta content="USD" itemprop="priceCurrency">
    </div>
    <div class="offer" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
      <div itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/IndividualProduct">
        <span class="sku" itemprop="sku">scb-ov2</span>
        – (<span itemprop="weight">16 oz.</span>)
      </div>
      <div class="price">$<span itemprop="price">20.99</span></div>
      <meta content="USD" itemprop="priceCurrency">
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer and really helped me out thank you

Comment: I'm looking at the schema.org specs for [`IndividualProduct`](http://schema.org/IndividualProduct) and I'm no longer sure if it's the best type for the itemscope used to list individual item SKU and prices (`IndividualProduct` is meant for "A single, identifiable product instance (e.g. a laptop with a particular serial number)"). Another option would be [`ProductModel`](http://schema.org/ProductModel), although I'm not sure if it's a better fit or not.

Comment: It is not the best solution because Yandex treats as incorrect a Product microdata with multiple `offers` properties.

Comment: @Finesse, the [Yandex structured data validator](https://webmaster.yandex.com/tools/microtest/) complained about a missing product description. I added that to the code above. Did that fix the problem you observed?

Comment: @thirdender The Google and Yandex microdata validators behaviours differ from how the real search bots work. For example, the Google validator doesn't execute JavaScript while the Google bot does. The Yandex validator says that a product microdata with multiple `offers` properties is OK while the Yandex bot doesn't makes a product snippets for such pages (you should you a single AggregateOffer instead).

Comment: this no longer appears to validate with Google's Structured Data Testing tool - *"One of offers or review or aggregateRating should be provided."*

Answer (score 2):

I think I would have one `Product` that contains multiple `Offer`s, one per size.  The limitation, of course, is that it doesn't offer a formal means for specifying multiple product IDs, but perhaps you could informally put those in the `Offer`'s Description or URL property.  That's not an exact fit, but maybe it's close enough.

Another option is to join the Public Vocabs email list (lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs), which asserts that it is "the place to propose extensions, new types, or feedback from deployment experience with the existing vocabulary" (lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2011Oct/0162.html), and propose a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you. Implemented it the way you described it, however I'm looking forward to a proper solution.

Comment: You're welcome.  When you find that proper solution, come back and post it here so we can all learn.

Comment: I agree with James that there's not really a great solution. I've posed the question to the [mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2012Jan/0072.html), but it's not gotten any traction. Trouble is: I'm not at all sure what the solution would be.

Comment: It is not the best solution because Yandex treats a Product microdata with multiple offers properties as incorrect and doesn't makes a product snippet for such page.

Answer (score 1):

I think *ProductGroup* is the key. See https://schema.org/ProductGroup

I have a similar quest and I find it hard to match google suggestions for xml product feeds with schema.org specs. Thing is, that feed should include each *sku* as single feed item (each shoe size separately), yet wa sell them as one product with different sizes. Our developer uses *AggregateOffer* to link all the sizes together, but specs does not allow each *offer* item to differ or even include an *sku* field. *Product* seems to suit the case better. Both *sku* and +size* are valid, properties of *Product*. Different sizes should be linked by *productGroup*.

In your case I would look into *ProductModel* for grouping multiple *Product* options, as it allows *PropertyValue* fields. See https://schema.org/ProductModel

Comment: This is the correct solution!
```A ProductGroup represents a group of Products that vary only in certain well-described ways, such as by size, color, material etc.```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a slightly different way of thinking about this particular web page. Instead of thinking about this specific webpage as a 'Product' page, think about it as a 'WebPage' type. This 'WebPage' then actually contains three different 'Products', each with their own 'Offer' and their own 'productID'. When you're saying that each size has it's own EAN, that's a big indicator to me that each size's price/size/id should be contained inside if it's own 'Product' div.

Comment: Well, this would force me to use a lot of hidden divs - what google does not like or meta-tags, according to schema.org, which is not w3-valid.

Comment: I would discourage the meta-tag approach as well. Only you can speak to the design of your site and whether or not it can be done, but if these other product divs would be revealed when the user selects the different sizes from a dropdown, then this is normal javascript div-revealing behavior and not cloaking information.

Answer (score 0):

This is what Google says to do: Use itemOffered The item being sold. Typically, this includes a nested Product, but it can also contain other item types or free text.

Comment: Could you go more into detail?

Answer (score 0):

All the different variations should be represented as separate `Product`s with separate `Offer`s. Use `Product`'s `isSimilarTo` and `isRelatedTo` properties to link them together.

reference: http://schema.org/Product

Answer (score 0):

Consider using "AggregateOffer" for the product, than within each offer specify each size as a different "itemOffered"

https://schema.org/itemOffered

> While several common expected types are listed explicitly in this definition, others can be used. Using a second type, such as Product or a subtype of Product, can clarify the nature of the offer.